# Using Perl to expand abbreviations in an array?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, variables, scope

I'm not sure if this can be done, or at least the way I'm attempting it. Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is answered elsewhere. I've tried several different scripts, none successful, right now this is what I have. Please excuse any poor syntax/sloppy code, I'm very new to Perl -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $file1 = "testShort.txt";
open(FH, "< $file1") or die "Can't open $file1 for read: $!";
my @Array;
while (<FH>) {
  push(@Array, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close $file1: $!";

# spelling out abbreviations
# opening text files of abbreviations and full text
my $file3 = "abbr.txt";
open(FH, "< $file3") or die "Can't open $file3 for read: $!";
my @abbr;
while (<FH>) {
  push(@abbr, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close $file1: $!";

my $file4 = "full.txt";
open(FH, "< $file4") or die "Can't open $file4 for read: $!";
my @full;
while (<FH>) {
  push(@full, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close $file4: $!";

# attempt to expand abbreviations throughout array
my $k = 0;
foreach (@Array) {
  while ($k < @Array) {
    $_ =~ s/ $abbr[$k] | $abbr[$k]. /$full[$k] /;
    $k++;
  }
}

print @Array;
```

I do actually have separate code to accept "shortTest.txt" at the command line, and in the future I'll be using this code as part of another script, running it against multiple text files from the command line, although I don't think that makes a difference?.

I have the regex working as I want it to without variables, and outside of the while loop (easy part...) As I've read more and more I'm thinking I'm just making some logical error in how that loops, and need completely different code, and as far as the variables go, I've looked it up 100 times, tried s/\Q @var \E/\Q $var2 \E/, etc.

any help is appreciated, I could probably spend a couple hours reading up and figure this out, and I plan to soon, but right now, I'm hoping for some help

---Just eidting this to say thank you for the help on this, great community, I'm hoping in some other areas I can try and give back, maybe eventually help on basic Perl questions

Comment: The global flag, and eval flag `s///ge` and `QuoteMeta()` is probably what you want, but what is this dot metachar `$abbr[$k].` for?

Comment: You're building your @abbr array with line returns at the end of your data.  You probably want to chomp the lines before building your array.

Comment: @sln - that was something I thought I took out, but missed half that or... I need to concatenate a . on the end of the string variable, inside the s/// if possible, otherwise I'll do it and store as another variable concatenated with the string. I meant to take out entire or in s/// and come back to figure that out later

Comment: Something like `s/ \Q[ ]$abbr[$k]\E\.?[ ]/$full[$k]." "/xge;` Taken out the alternation since I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @TCooper - On the subsitution side `s//<here>/g` its literal, there is no interpolation. You have to use the eval option to substitue variables.

Comment: @sln Not true. `perl -e '$_ = "foo"; $bar = "baz"; s/foo/$bar/; print'` prints `baz`.

Comment: Wow, thats new to me. Actually yep, its been a long time since I Perled this.

Comment: @ ThisSuitIsBlackNot - But, any hint of catenation or quoting on the substitution side must be evaled. Yeah, now I remember. Is this right?

Comment: One of the first lessons is how to spell "Perl" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things, use lexical file handles instead of type globs.  Be sure to chomp your data, especially if you're going to be using it to search and replace.  You're unlikely to be wanting to translate Mr.\n -> Mister\n but actually Mr. -> Mister.

After that, creating a single regex to do the search and replace is advantageous so you don't have clobber previous changes.  It probably would be wise to add boundary conditions to the regex as well, so that you don't replace the middle of words.  Hopefully this will help fix at least some of the issues with your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $abbrevfile = 'abbr.txt';
my $fullfile = 'full.txt';
my $datafile = 'testShort.txt';

open my $abbrevfh, $abbrevfile or die "Can't open $abbrevfile: $!";
my @abbrevs = <$abbrevfh>;
chomp(@abbrevs);
close $abbrevfh;

open my $fullfh, $fullfile or die "Can't open $fullfile: $!";
my @fulls = <$fullfh>;
chomp(@fulls);
close $fullfh;

# Build translation regex and hash;
if (@abbrevs != @fulls) {
    die "Data mismatch.  abbrevs and full must be same length\n";
}
my $abbrev_re = join '|', map {"\Q$_\E\.?"} @abbrevs;
my %trans = ();
@trans{@abbrevs} = @fulls;

open my $datafh, $datafile or die "Can't open $datafile: $!";
while (<$data$fh>) {
    s/\b($abbrev_re)\b/$trans{$1}/g;
    print;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is cool, creating a hash of abbrev's keys. This might be over his head.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new script to test this, and once I fixed full->fulls, I only get this back - Use of uninitialized value $data in <HANDLE> at quick.pl line 30.
readline() on unopened filehandle at quick.pl line 30.  -  I did check to make sure the file locations lined up, and the naming matched to read the file in

Comment: @TCooper - change `$data` to `$datafh`.

Comment: I corrected while (<$data>) to while (<$datafh>) to fix that issue.

Comment: yeah, I actually just realized that after I posted, thanks again! I still don't have it working like I need, but I can tell this code will be a lot more effective/time efficient, especially when I'm running it with large files

Comment: This is terrific, I just love Perl. @TCooper, you can always upvote and/or accept if it helped ya. Good Luck! and thanks Miller.

Comment: Like sln said, it's a bit over my head, but that's how I learn right? I won't use code until I understand it, but having the code to run, with test files where you already know what output you want/should get, can be incredibly helpful, at least for me. Thanks again, I'll probably be back soon, but going to at least try more on my own first

Comment: Also, I would upvote, but I don't have 15 rep to, I just signed up before I posted with questions, I only read older posts for answers before today

Comment: can I ask for an explanation, or even some pseudo-code, from '#Build translation regex and hash;' - '@trans{@abbrevs} = @full;' right now it's running and just printing the array as is, I've been trying to look it up piece by piece, and will continue too, but again, if anyone is willing to impart knowledge... I appreciate it

Comment: @trans{@abbrev} is a hash slice.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices  First you might need to learn about hashes though, which you can find earlier on that page.  Just think of it associative arrays.